# Reserve Ammo Formula

Tags: unity-game-engine, frame-rate

Here's my problem. I'm working on an FPS with a Counter-Strike/TF2esque ammunition system. My problem is, my current formula gives some weird, glitchy results when one reloads from a 1/1 ammo state (as in one chambered, one reserve). My system will produce an additional round from thin air. This is my current formula:

```
myReserve = myReserve - (magSize - boolet);
        boolet = magSize;
        if (myReserve < 0){
            myReserve = 0;
}
```

Does anybody have a programmatic solution to this (or even better, pure math)?
Code is UnityScript, if relevant.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code explicitly creates ammo with that if statement, as you are turning negative myReserve values into zero. Let me refactor your code, this is exactly what you code does now:

```
var transferedAmmo = magSize - boolet;
myReserve -= transferedAmmo;
boolet += transferedAmmo;
if (myReserve < 0)
    myReserve = 0;
```

If you need to ask if myReserve < 0, you should already tell that you are doing something wrong. The transferedAmmo should never be greater than myReserve:

```
var transferedAmmo = Mathf.Min(magSize - boolet, myReserve);
myReserve -= transferedAmmo;
boolet += transferedAmmo;
```

Comment: Your code is C++, a heads up to anybody else using this solution. Works perfectly.

Comment: oops, now it's javascript

Comment: Sorry for late, but that's fine. It really wasn't that difficult to change the declarations.